# Instantiating Groovy class within Java class

Tags: java, groovy

I have a groovy class

```
@Immutable
class StatusCode {
final int statusCode
}
```

I want to create an object of this class in another Java class say, Test.Java. But when I use,

```
public class Test{
 StatusCode statusCode;
 public void setStatusCode(int statusCode)
 {
   this.statusCode = new StatusCode(statusCode);
 }
}
```

It says the constructor is missing. How do I instantiate this object ?

Comment: could you post the details of the error here?

Answer (score 1):

Groovy code can be compiled into Java bytecode using [groovyc](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Compiling+Groovy). This will give you a valid Java class you can reference from any other Java class. You do still need to have the groovy runtime JAR on your claspath.

It's possible the Groovy compiler will generate the desired constructor for you, but I'm not sure. If not, you'd need to explicitly code it in the Groovy class.

Comment: If you are using groovy 1.8, you can use the [TupleConstructor](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/transform/TupleConstructor.html) annotation to add the constructors for you

Comment: @Tim - the Immutable annotation creates tuple constructors, plus a map constructor.

Comment: @winstaan74 so it does...sorry about that :-/